# PROJ: proj_create: Error -7: unknown unit conversion id

Tags: proj, bash, wrf-model

I am attempting to use a bash script to reproject wrf output using the following:

`${gdal} -of GTiff -a_srs '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_1=30 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=42.1200065612793 +lon_0=-72.05000305175781 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=degrees +no_defs' -a_ullr -74.98987 45.74738 -69.98447 40.22901 NETCDF:${data}"wrfout_d03_${loopdate}00.nc":${array[$index]} ${data}${modeldate}/wrf_${modeldate}_${1}_${array3[$index]}.tif &`

While this code worked perfectly well with previous versions of PROJ, I am using version 6.3.0 and am met with the following error:

`ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: Error -7: unknown unit conversion id`
`ERROR 1: Failed to process SRS definition: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_1=30 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=42.1200065612793 +lon_0=-72.05000305175781 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=degrees +no_defs`

Has anyone else run into this issue?